# C++ runtime error message is not printed in MSVC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, runtime-error

My C++ compiler(MSVC++ 14.2 in Windows 10) ends without printing any error message when there is a runtime error like a segmentation fault.

For example,

```
std::shared<Foo> foo;
auto b = foo->bar; // segmenation fault, but ends without the error message
...
```

The compiler does not print the error message like `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Is there a way to set the compiler to print a runtime error message?

Comment: Building a C++ program is a multi-step process: Compile the source into an object file; Link all object files and libraries into an executable program file; Run the executable program file. Run-time errors happens when you run the program, not when you run the compiler.

Comment: Also, "segmentation fault" is a POSIX (e.g. Linux or macOS) specific run-time error. Windows have the same *kind* of error, but it's not called "segmentation fault". Furthermore, dereferencing a null pointer leads to *undefined behavior*. It *might* cause a crash, it *might* seem to work, or it *might* summon [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: MSVC++ gave you a segfault? Segfaults are errors raised by objects compiled using gcc right? Are you sure you are using MSVC++ and not mingw? For MSVC++ you can use [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=vs-2019) to *catch* these errors.

Comment: I don't think the term 'segmentation fault' is OS-specific although the term used in error message could be different(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Comment: @Roy2511 Doesn't MSVC++ give me any runtime error message if SEH is not installed? It is my first time to program C++ in Windows, so I would like to check whether there is 'segmentation fault' like an error message in MSVC?

Comment: The usual windows termination behavior upon an unhandled access violation (the windows term for a segfault) is to produce a dialog rather than print anything to the console, even in programs that target the console subsystem.